# Catch error before hand in golang

Tags: go

I have the following code and when the attribute `debug` is missing the program crashed with error which difficult to understand. I want to catch this error and provide better message but what I’ve tried is not working 
I want to avoid.

```
var jsonParsedApp *gabs.Container = nil    

debug := jsonParsedApp.Path("debug").Data()
//This is what I’ve tried
if debug == nil {
    log.Println(“Property debug is missing “)
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context the next time! While @zerkms has excellent psychic debugging skills and was able to help you, that `github.com/Jeffail/gabs` package is certainly not a part of the Go standard library so you really ought to mention what package that `gabs` idenfifier identifies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `Exists` method

```
if jsonParsedApp.Exists("debug") {
    // you can safely read it here
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs/blob/master/gabs.go#L129